# How to use GnuGk as a H.323 gateway/proxy

Tags: voip

Please help me by letting me know how to use GNU gatekeeper, I have installed in on a Ubuntu server but I do not know how to use it.

What I need is, now I have a Cisco CMS and enabled H323 bridge on it, so people are able to join CMS simply by dialing the IP of CMS from LAN.
CMS(LAN IP)
I want other people to join from Internet but we have a firewall in between LAN and WAN network, but this firewall does not support ALG feature, so NAT CMS to a public IP does not work.

CMS(LAN IP)------------------firewall(Public IP)

My plan is to install a GNU GK like this:

CMS(LAN IP)----------------(LAN IP)GNUGK(public IP)-------------Internet

so people from Internet just need to dial the public IP of GNUGK and GNUGK will pass the traffic to CMS as a proxy.

while I have gnugk installed and configured and running but it is not working as I expected.

here is the configuration for GnuGk

[Gatekeeper::Main]
Fortytwo=42
TimeToLive=600
Home=114.255.xxx.xxx
StatusPort=7000

[RoutedMode]
GKRouted=1
CallSignalPort=11720
H245Routed=1
H245TunnelingTranslation=1
H245PortRange=56000-56999
AcceptUnregisteredCalls=1
SupportNATedEndpoints=1
EnableH46018=1
H46018NoNat=0
EnableH46023=1
H46023STUN=stun.h323.net
ENUMservers=enum.daileddigits.com,nrenum.net,e164.arpa
RDSservers=rds.h323.net

[RoutingPolicy]
default=explicit,internal,enum,srv,rds,dns

[Proxy]
Enable=1
RTPPortRange=55000-55999
RTPMultiplexing=1
RTPMultiplexPort=2776
RTCPMultiplexPort=2777

[GkStatus::Auth]
FileIPAuth=required;RRQ,LRQ,Setup

[FileIPAuth]
any=allow

[ModeSelection]
114.255.177.246=PROXY

[RasSrv::Neighbors]
GK1=CiscoGk

[Neighbor::GK1]
GatekeeperIdentifier=GK1
Host=10.100.9.20
SendPrefixes=*
AcceptPrefixes=*
ForwardLRQ=always

[RasSrv::RRQFeatures]
SupportDynamicIP=1
OverwriteEPOnSameAddress=1

[RasSrv::LRQFeatures]
AcceptNonNeighborLCF=1
AcceptNonNeighborLRQ=1

[LogFile]
Rotate=Weekly
RotateDay=Sun
RotateTime=03:59
Filename=/var/log/gatekeeper.log

When I use this configuration file to run GnuGk and try to dial 114.255.xxx.xxx, nothing happens. The log does not give me any clues. It seems the signal does not even reach this IP.

The IP is pingable from internet.

I tried to understand how GnuGk works and I really cannot understand its manual.

Answer (score 0):

You are shooting yourself in the foot by setting way too many switches.

If GnuGk is running **on the firewall**, then it should be able to auto-detect the internal and external IPs automatically. Maybe you will need to tell it the internal networks, take a look at the config example `etc/proxy.ini`.

Another option would be to run GnuGk **behind your firewall** and set the config switch ExternalIP=x.x.x.x to your public IP and forward port ranges to GnuGk.

Comment: really appreciate your reply. now I did as you suggested: install GnuGK behind firewall and applied HOME IP and external IP and use firewall to map this two IP and allow the necessary port. However, I do not know how people call the public ip and gnugk could redirect them into the internal cms, shall I configure the internal cms in GNUGK in the neighour module or   routing module.

Comment: Yes, you could add the Cisco as a neighbor or as a gateway (a "permanent endpoint" in GnuGk's terms).